# Refresh JFrame after UPDATE, INSERT etc

Tags: java, jframe, refresh

I have a main frame and many other frames which add, update, or delete rows in my database (SQLite). How can I refresh the contents in the main frame after, for example, the 'Add' frame closes and has added a new row in the database? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap something round whatever class is doing the database update calls. Write a class that allows you to pass it the row to be inserted, or whatever, and have it perform the update and then notify anything that's listening for updates. You can then have your main window listen out for updates.

This is an *observer* pattern, which is a common design pattern in Java, and used heavily throughout the JDK. See, for instance, the `ActionListener` class.